# Class TKPotentiometer has no member named 'read'

Tags: arduino-uno, potentiometer

I am testing a set-up using the TinkerKit shield for Arduino Uno, and a few TinkerKit inputs and outputs. I have an issue with the code provided on the [TinkerKit website](http://www.tinkerkit.com/linear-pot/) for the potentiometer component:

```
#include <TinkerKit.h>

// creating the object 'pot' that belongs to the 'TKPotentiometer' class
TKPotentiometer pot(I0);

// creating the object 'led' that belongs to the 'TKLed' class 
TKLed led(O0);                              

int brightnessVal = 0;  // value read from the pot

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the potentiometer's value:
  brightnessVal = pot.read();            

  // set the led brightness
  led.brightness(brightnessVal);       

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("brightness = " );                      
  Serial.println(brightnessVal);      

  // wait 10 milliseconds before the next loop
  delay(10);                    
}
```

I get an error message when compiling:

```
Class TKPotentiometer has no member named 'read'
```

According to [this webpage](http://www.tinkerkit.com/linear-pot/), though, `read` should be a member of the class. Why am I receiving this message?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I finished writing the question, it came to my mind that perhaps I misspelled something, so I looked for a file in the Menu's sketchbook that I could load.

With my surprise, I found the same exact code as I posted, with a little difference:

`pot.read()` was substituted with `pot.get()`